# Deallocating memory allocated in a function

Tags: c, function, malloc

Take this code for example:

```
int *doSomething(void) {
    int *something = malloc(sizeof(int));
    return something;
}

int main() {
    int *point = doSomething();
    //code does something...
    free(point);
}
```

I am wondering if I have to deallocate memory allocated in `doSomething()`, like after `return something;` do I have to do `free(something);`? Or doing `free(point);` also clears `something`?
Or maybe I have to do `free(something);` in the `main` function, before the code ends?

Comment: I think last one wouldn't work, since something should be ''visible'' only in doSomething function...

Comment: Your current code is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you don't have to deallocate memory in `doSomething()`, `free(point)` should free the memory `malloc()`ed in `doSomething()` provided that the pointer is not incremented (*involved in pointer arithmetic*), because the pointer you MUST pass to `free()` MUST have been returned by one of the *`alloc()` functions.

What you should be careful with is accessing `point` in `main()` before checking that `point != NULL`.

**NOTE**: When you say **clears** you should know that memory is not cleared it's released to be used again only, clearing it would be unnecessary and expensive.

Comment: Ok! So basically, if at the end of code ''something'' and ''point'' have still the same address, doing free(point); on main function, will also clear ''something'' allocated in the doSomething function. Am I right?

Comment: "_No you don't have to_" -- You should mention which question of the OP you've answered to.

Comment: @THZ Yes. Correct. Note that the pointer `something` will be deleted as soon as the function ends, but the allocated memory segment doesn't.

Comment: Thanks both of you. :)

Comment: @THZ I think you're confused between a pointer *variable* and the *value* that the pointer holds.  It is the value that matters to `free`, not the actual variable that holds the value.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i don't understand what you talking about. If i'm correct, "something" holds the first element of memory allocated dinamically (which i can use later like an array by incrementing the address), also, returning "something" to "point" would give "point" the same address of "something", so they also hold the same value.

Comment: @THZ yes exactly, the two pointers are said to point to the same address, since that address was returned by `malloc()` then it has to be passed to `free()` when you know that you no longer need the data the pointer points to.

Comment: @THZ - `malloc` returns a value.  That value must be the same value you use when you use `free`.  It is that simple, it isn't more complicated than that.  You're overcomplicating things by thinking about what the names of your variables are.

Comment: @iharob so, as I said before, doing free(point); on main function, will free also "something" pointer, because they have same address. :)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sorry, but I just didn't know that doing free(point); would also clear "something", now it's clear. Thats why i asked :)

Comment: @THZ "_returning "something" to "point" would give "point" the same address of "something"_" Its not 'the address of `something`', but 'the address to which `something` points to' that is returned. Your choice of words are misleading...

Comment: @THZ "_doing free(point); on main function, will free also "something" pointer, because they have same address_" -- 'because they have the same addresses' is wrong. Its because they *point* to the same memory address.

Comment: @CoolGuy yeah sorry. Just chose the wrong words, but I think i got the notion :D

Comment: @THZ - Let's say that `malloc` returned `0x12345678`.  You **must** call `free` with the address `0x12345678`.  By hook or by crook, the address you pass to `free` must be that address.   Doesn't matter what pointer has that address, how that address was passed back and forth between functions, whether you assigned that address to another pointer variable, etc.  All `free` cares about is `0x12345678`.  If you do what the answer states, i.e. increment the address by 1, and erroneously give free `0x12345679`, then that is an error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I got it! Thanks for the answer. I will check at end of my code (it's not short as that example lol) that both pointers, point to the same address to be sure it will be working :)

Answer (score -4):

As a rule of thumb, any call to `malloc` has to be succeeded at a later moment by a call to `free`. Of course, the parameter that you give to `free` has to be the return value of the `malloc`. However, in your particular case, you've already reached the end of your program (end of `main` function), so you don't have to worry about that memory, because it will be returned to the OS anyway. Calling `free` there is more like a *pedantic* habit and it also shows that you are aware of what memory your program is using.

Things get much worse when you do stuff like:

```
int *p = malloc(...);
/* do some stuff */
p = malloc(...);
```

In the example above, the chunk of memory allocated by the first malloc is lost forever (aka as long as your program runs).

Comment: Although it's true, I was initially afraid that you was telling the OP not to worry about freeing memory. If this was not the `main()` function the lack of `free()` (*if the function does not intend to return the pointer*) would be a severe problem in the long term (*if the program intends to run for long time*). So a PEDANTIC but very good habit it is.

Comment: That's true. However, I did not say anything false. It's not unfreed, but reachable memory that causes memory leaks, it's the unreachable memory that hurts us. There is nothing wrong with reachable, unfreed memory (if you still need it, of course).

Comment: There are real world environments where returning from `main()` does not deallocate memory.   Not everyone uses operating systems that clean up after processes.    In the long run, programmers who rely on the host system cleaning up their memory get into trouble - for example, when moving code into functions that allocate memory repeatedly, but never release it.

Comment: I agree that you can cause more problems if you don't explicitly `free` memory, but I think that people take things too literally and don't filter information at all, just trust whatever they find on the first link that Google shows. I thought it's important to understand, even as a C newbie, what actually happens with memory. Besides, it's not returning from main what causes memory to be deallocated, not at all. It's finishing the process and unmapping its pages from the physical memory (action done by the OS).